# What is the MacPorts analog of brew install --HEAD (does it allow you to specify a git tag)?

Tags: macos, installation, git, macports

There is a bug in a piece of software I have installed, to fix it it is suggested we install the latest (unreleased) version with brew from github using,

```
brew install --HEAD chunkwm
```

This software is also available on MacPorts, which is what I used to install it? Does MacPorts provide any such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

My assumption at this point is "No" it's not available, and that MacPorts doesn't provide this kind of functionality. The syntax for `port install` is currently as of 2.5.2,

```
port [-vdqysbckpotf] [-D portdir] install
     [--no-rev-upgrade] [--unrequested]
     [[portname | pseudo-portname | port-expressions | port-url]]
     [+/-variant ...]
```

You can see that it takes a URL to a port, not a repo. The `variants` are defined [inside the portfile](https://github.com/koekeishiya/portfiles/blob/master/aqua/chunkwm/Portfile) which don't seem to provided for a git branch or tag.